# Table with name 'X' is not defined

Tags: swift, azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I downloaded the swift and Xamarin.Android version of quick start application (To Do Item) and it worked fine, then I added some additional models like Country and tried to fetch data from both applications and I get the following errors:

iOS Swift Error:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.Microsoft.MicrosoftAzureMobile.ErrorDomain Code=-1153 "Table 'Country' not found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Table 'Country' not found}
```

Android Xamarin Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Table with name 'Country' is not defined.
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore.GetTable (System.String tableName) [0x00024] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore.ExecuteQuery (System.String tableName, System.String sql, IDictionary`2 parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore.MobileServiceSQLiteStore+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<ReadAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00022] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:111 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2502 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext+<ReadAsync>d__25.MoveNext () [0x00179] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider+<Execute>d__8`1[T].MoveNext () [0x001b8] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider+<Execute>d__7`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000a5] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncTable`1+<ToListAsync>d__23[T].MoveNext () [0x00060] in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3415/7db2aac3/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at swoup.ToDoActivity+<OnCreate>d__7.MoveNext () [0x001c1] in C:\Users\Developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SwoupAndroidTest\swoup\ToDoActivity.cs:68
```

On the browser it returns the expected result https://swoup.azurewebsites.net/tables/country?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0

Comment: That's definitely weird. Can you try adding logging on the client to see what's going on?  See [Log outgoing requests in your mobile client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#log-outgoing-requests-in-your-mobile-client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was very easy, for Xamarin.Android you only needed to define the table in InitLocalStoreAsync, I suppose it something similar for other languages.

```
private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
{
    // new code to initialize the SQLite store
    string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), localDbFilename);

    if (!File.Exists(path)) {
        File.Create(path).Dispose();
    }

    var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
    store.DefineTable<ToDoItem>();
    store.DefineTable<Country>(); // Here I defining new table

    // Uses the default conflict handler, which fails on conflict
    // To use a different conflict handler, pass a parameter to InitializeAsync. For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521416
    await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
}
```